# How to add two cells in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions, cell-array

I have B <1x3 cell> like this:

```
B{1} = [2 1 19 22 29 13 14]
B{2} = [11 12 6 3 4 2 5]
B{3} = [3 2 23 13 4 7 8]
```

And I want to add A <4x2 cell> like this:

```
A = {'a' '-1'; 'b' '1'; 'c' '2'; 'd' ''}
```

I tried like this:

```
for j=1:length(A)
  for i=1:1:length(B)
    C = B{i} + A{j,2};
  end
end
```

what I get is "Matrix dimensions must agree."
How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` holds characters. You need to convert the strings to numbers to be able to add them to `B`. Use e.g. `str2double`:

```
for j=1:length(A)
  for i=1:1:length(B)
    C = B{i} + str2double(A{j,2});
  end
end
```

Note that the last value in A is `''`, which is converted to a `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains several problems:

First is shown in @angainor answer. You need to convert string to number.

Second one is following. B{i} is matrix of size 7x1, A{j,2} is single number. Do you want to add this number to all elements of matrix B{i}? In this case, you should write something like:

```
B{i} + str2double(A{j,2}) * ones(size(B{i}))
```

Third problem is that length(A) command will return total number of elements in A, e.g. 4*2=8.
Therefore, you will have error: Can not access element A{5,2}.
You need replace this line with

```
for j = 1:size(A,1)
```